# Paycheck contract keeps trying to send to a new random contract address/not working properly

Tags: solidity, remix, address.transfer, payments

I'm very new to Solidity and facing a dumb problem. I'm trying to create a contract that pays my employee Mike (ex).

Here, `withdraw()` function worked as expected. It returns ETH to my wallet again from the contract after I funded (`fund()`). Also the contract balance(`balance()`) is updated accordingly.

However, for `payMike` function, when I put my wallet address to `_to` and put the value in `paycheckInUsd` here for instance, 111 (around 0.1 eth), like the photo I attached below, it keeps trying to send to a randomly generated new contract address(**0xEOO~**). Also even after the transaction confirmed, the balance of the contract is not updated which I assume means the `transfer` in `payMike` didn't work or I wrote something very wrong. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here or any advice on my code would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

// error minimumUSDError();

contract FundMe {

    mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
    address public owner; 

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender; 
    }

    function fund() public payable {
        // $500 in gwei terms
        uint256 minimumUSD = 50 * 10 ** 18;
        require(minimumUSD < getConversionRate(msg.value), "You need to spend more ETH!");
        // if (msg.value < minimumUSD) {
        //     revert minimumUSDError();
        // }

        addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        // what the ETH -> USD conversion rate  
    
    }

    function getVersion() public view returns(uint256) {
        // we have a contract that has these functions defined in that interface, located at this address
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
        return priceFeed.version();
   }

   function getPrice() public view returns(uint256) {
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e);
        (,int256 answer,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return uint256(answer*1000000000);
   }

    // 1000000000
   function getConversionRate(uint256 ethAmount) public view returns(uint256) {
       uint256 ethPrice = getPrice();
       uint256 ethAmountInUsd = (ethPrice * ethAmount) / 100000000000000000;
       return ethAmountInUsd;
   }

   modifier onlyOwner {
       require(msg.sender == owner);
       _;
   }

   function withdraw() public onlyOwner payable {
       // transfer, send, call
       payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);
   }


   function payMike(address payable _to, uint256 paycheckInUsd) public payable {
       uint256 ethPrice = getPrice() ;
       uint256 paycheckInWei = (paycheckInUsd) / (ethPrice * 10);
       _to.transfer(paycheckInWei);
   } 

   function balance() public view returns(uint256) {
       return address(this).balance;
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide example values for `paycheckInUsd` and `ethPrice`? My suspicious is that a unit is wrong, so the wrong calculation returns an unexpected value.

Comment: Hi Thanks much for the comment, yes the unit seems to be totally wrong a bit so just edited but still if I run the function `payMike`, remix keeps trying to do sth with a random new account... shouldn't `_to.transfer(amount)` work properly like sending `amount` in Wei to `_to` account?

Comment: It seems it is an interaction with the contract. If you deploy a new contract it will change it address. The transfer from a contract is called an "internal transaction" and metamask do not show them.

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much! Now I also figured out that chainlink AggregatorV3 contract uses 8 decimals Have a wonderful Monday ser!

Comment: It will be nice if you could add the solution as answer so it can help someone else in similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Ismael’s comments above, I could figure out what happened.

First of all, those new random addresses that popped up whenever I tried to run the `transfer` function was the address of this contract. Every time I (click the button) “deploy” a contract, a new address will be assigned to this contract.

As this transaction was sent from the contract address to EOA, it is considered as an “internal transaction” so we can’t see this transaction under the activity bar in Metamask.

Also, in the `getPrice` function, I was wrong about the unit. Chainlink’s AggregatorV3Interface uses 8 decimals. I tried to match all numbers in 18 decimals, so I had to add 10 more zeros not 9 more.